# Animate a menu on page load

Tags: jquery, html, menu, load, html-lists

I am trying to have my ul menu fly in from the left side of the page when the document loads using jquery. How would I go about doing this? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `jQuery.animate` to animate element.

**Example**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('ul').animate({left:'20px'},800);
});
```

I have created other [`DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/njzhj/) for you to see it.

Answer (score 0):

Launching off of what Dipesh Parmar started, I've made [another working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UJqA3/1/) with a few key differences:

1. You want it to come from the right, and slide to the left, see `var startPos = 0 - objWidth;`
2. You likely want it to STOP before going off of the page, see `left: $(document).width() - objWidth - 15`  to move it to the edge of the page, displaying the full object (plus a little padding)

Since the demo is a little bit overly complicated likely for what you want, here's what the code you're after boils down to

```
var plane = $("#plane");
plane.css('left', plane.width()*-1); // Initially position the object off the page
plane.animate({
    left: $(document).width() - $("#plane").width() - 15 // Go to the right edge, show the whole object, and some padding
}, 3000, 'linear') // Action takes 3000 milliseconds in a linear motion
```

Check out jQuery's animation documentation for more http://api.jquery.com/animate/